# How to map different columns of ONE table into ONE column of ONE table using Talend

Tags: talend, tmap, expressionbuilder

I have one table with different columns.  The columns belong to an **Id, x and y**.  I would like to map those columns into **One unique ID, X and Y** using talend:
I have a connection to my DB from MySQL to Talend.  Im adding my table as a "MySQLInput".
**The table looks like:**

```
idN| XN  |YN   | idT |XT   | YT
1  | 2.5 | 4.5 | 2   | 6.9 | 2.7
2  | 6.9 | 2.7 | 7   | 9.9 | 2.1
5  | 4.6 | 6.6 | 9   | 1.3 | 5.5
7  | 3.2 | 7.8 | 6   | 3.2 | 3.1
```

I want this table as a result after mapping with talend:

```
idU | XU | YU
1   | 2.5 | 4.5
2   | 6.9 | 2.7
5   | 4.6 | 6.6
6   | 3.2 | 3.1
7   | 3.2 | 7.8
7   | 9.9 | 2.1
9   | 1.3 | 5.5
```

I try to do that:

[image]

But the result **is not what i expect:**

```
IDU | XU | YU
1 | 2.5  | 4.5
2 | 6.9  | 2.7
5 | 4.6  | 6.6
7 | 3.2  | 7.8
```

I have tried also doing this:

[image]

using that expression but code gives me an error.

I also tried to create my own routine and using it in the  Expression builder but still not working.

Does anyone have hint about how to conduct this mapping, or what component to use.
The thing is that i don't have only 2 times the same columns but three or more in the same table and I need to map them all at one final and unique column per each one of the similar variables.

thanks for taking your time to reading this , and double thanks to answer it :)

Comment: Can you please format your data and expected output in a tabular format, so that it becomes more readable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using `tSplitRow`:

[image]

You need to split each incoming row into 2 rows: one with `idN, XN, YN` and the 2nd one having the columns `idT, XT, YT`. tSplitRow has the columns `id, X, Y`.
Then use a `tUniqRow` to filter out duplicates, like this :

[image]

And the output :

```
.--+---+---.
|tLogRow_5 |
|=-+---+--=|
|id|X  |Y  |
|=-+---+--=|
|1 |2.5|4.5|
|2 |6.9|2.7|
|7 |9.9|2.1|
|5 |4.6|6.6|
|9 |1.3|5.5|
|7 |3.2|7.8|
|6 |3.2|3.1|
'--+---+---'
```

Comment: wow! is perfect! you saved my life! So sad that I do not have the power to give you a point! You have my eternal gratitude.  By the way, I have problems performing that operation but because of size of the archive. Which component could be added to this model of yours to run the process. I try Changing the argument Xms and XMx but still doesn't work

Comment: I'm glad to be of help :) I'm not sure I understand your problem, could you please post another question with details and I'll look at it

Comment: thanks! I posed it there: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427368/talend-memory-issues-working-with-big-files